# Memory running out quickly, would separating as3 code solve it

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have so far been doing everything in one big big as3 file, but now I seem to be having problems with the memory pretty quickly, even if I am removing all the listeners and clearing all the containers all the time... would separating code in different as3 files help me prevent my flash slowing down?

Might be dumb question, but I dont want to start all the work of re-arranging the code, though at this point it is not too big of a work. Except maybe I have to figure out few things and re-do them since it probably wont work when they are in different files, but...

anyways, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The increase of memory has nothing to do with working with a single file, so splitting in different files/classes would not solve the problem without a refactoring of your code.

If, as you say, at this point the work it's not too big, I think you should seriously consider to refactor your code with a proper OOP structure. Will help you to debug your app, to help you finishing it and to maintain it in the future

Comment: if it is not too big of a job and big of a subject, can you please briefly explain? I have not gone to any programming school, this 11000 lines file is entirely based on what seems to work, looks logical to me... so, pretty much my first big project that I am working on free-time :P

Comment: well, explain what is OOP (Object Oriented Programming) it's not THAT fast and easy. Let's say that if you're working in AS3, you should split your code between different classes/objects, and not working with a huge file doing everything. This makes your code scalable and pretty easy to debug. The subject is huge....

Comment: okay, thats why I said if it´s not too big of a subject etc. :) so, I will start to re-think and re-do structure of my code, separating it... so far all have been in one big function that extends the movieclip (the main .fla) which again branches into hundreds of different functions with different purposes, listening them when needed and removing those listeners when not needed etc. *sigh* this seems to be quite of a setback :/ ah well, back to work...

Comment: well, what you're doing it's PROCEDURAL programming, that was the way we all programmed in AS2. Starting with OOP can be quite annoying at the beginning, but trust me, it's the best you can do! And it's the way lot of languages work - except JS.

Comment: yeah, it seems really hard to understand... this is HUGE setback *sigh* almost makes me consider of just switching and trying to learn some actual procedural programming language like C++... it felt so logical, now im lost heh...

Comment: you don't need to switch to OOP to fix your memory leak problem, you can still finish your work without refactoring. I just wanted to explain you that a OOP structure would help you a lot in this kind of situation. You DON'T HAVE to switch to OOP, it was just a suggestion...

Comment: okay... then I wonder how to fix this memory problem... hmh... any tips other than switching to OOP from procedural?

Comment: Well, if you prepare you can de-accept my answer, and see if someone can point you in the right direction using procedural techniques.... Feel free :)

Comment: thanks, but I think I`ll leave this, I think this might be helpful for some people, it certainly was for me, as a noobie I didnt even know my logic how I did things was called procedural method :) I`ll now make new question, thanks!